# Opening a new browser tab invalidates Django's CSRF token, preventing form submission

Tags: django, csrf, django-1.10

Opening a Django 1.10 application in a second browser tab refreshes the CSRF token.  This breaks all forms in the first tab -- i.e., previously opened forms can no longer be submitted because the old CSRF token is now invalid.

How do I avoid this behavior?

**Step-by-step example:**

1. User is viewing a form in Tab A.
2. User opens the application in Tab B.
3. User returns to Tab A and attempts to submit the form.
4. Error: Forbidden (403). CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

**Some details:**

I would really like to permit multi-tab browsing in the application.

The Django 1.10 [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#csrf) document a change to the CSRF mechanism:

> To protect against BREACH attacks, the CSRF protection mechanism now
>   changes the form token value on every request (while keeping an
>   invariant secret which can be used to validate the different tokens).

Django's [1.9 CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#why-not-use-a-new-token-for-each-request) has a really good description of the usability problem.  This paragraph has been removed in the [1.10 CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/), but it seems to describe the exact problem I'm encountering:

> Why not use a new token for each request?
>
> Generating a new token for each request is problematic from a UI
>   perspective because it invalidates all previous forms. Most users
>   would be very unhappy to find that opening a new tab on your site has
>   invalidated the form they had just spent time filling out in another
>   tab or that a form they accessed via the back button could not be
>   filled out.

Comment: This is really interesting. Since it's undocumented how to bypass this behaviour, I suggest you ask this on Django's IRC channel. You'll find some Django core developers there who might be able to answer.

Comment: Thanks @xyres, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using the @csrf_protect decorator in your views try using the @csrf_exempt decorator instead.

Before **views.py**:

```
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

    @csrf_protect
    def view(request):
         # Render Something
```

After **views.py**:

```
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

    @csrf_exempt
    def view(request):
         # Render Something
```

Sorry for the late Reply.
Better late than never I hope.

Comment: This is not a good idea. It disables csrf protection for the view.