# Session ID/Key overwritten on concurrent requests. Django staging server only allowing 1 request concurrently?

Tags: python, django

The problem that I am having is solely on my WSGI staging server when two users execute POST requests back to my server concurrently (or at any point), in doing so one of the two users is logged off. I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts as to what would cause multiple users to not be able to interact with the server?

The error occurs in this situation:

1. I open two different browser instances (one private/one public) on the same machine or different and go to my stg URL.
2. I log into two different user accounts (held in my database) on each of the browsers.
3. I click a button on each browser at the same time (Concurrent requests to server .. POST or GET)
4. Each of the users sessionid's are overwritten and each are eventually sent back to the login page. There is no "error" associated with anything other than that the user's cookie sessionid is overwritten.

I am building an app in django. I am using the session engine SESSION_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'.

I do use a login_required decorator:
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

So far I thought that it was a database connectivity but that is not the case; this is not the case because I can work through the error on my local machine (localhost) without ever encountering it which is weird.

This is solely an issue on the WSGI servers I am using.

EDIT: It seems like it is really just a concurrent issue with the  requests. I can have two users send post requests delayed until each post request is returned and neither will be logged out. The issue only occurs when the requests are concurrent. This occurs for all request types.

EDIT2: This is 100% an issue with the sessionid held via cookies. What would cause the sessionid to be overwritten on concurrent requests? Is is it a race condition in the authentication??

Edit3: My suspicion is that this continues to be a cookie/sessionid issue. I fixed my django to only use custom user model and authenticate through the default method. The sessionid gets overwritten on concurrent request.

If anyone has suggestions on what to check I would be all ears!

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example...

Comment: Ive faced the situation long back. But im not able to recollect what was causing it. 
But I vaguely remember that it had something to do with cookies being wiped out.

Comment: @ArunT Thanks! Yeah my personal belief is that the cookies are being wiped out. I will try going to storing my sessions via the database. I will make sure to update you when I do that. It is really weird and not really a code problem... I will also say that I found now that it is ANY concurrent request, get or post.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think this is my minimal reproducible example. The problem is not really one with code, but systems implementation. My code is correct because it works on my local dev server. The issue is somewhere after it gets translated to staging.

Comment: @BenP Yes. In my case too it was any request regardless of the method. 
May I suggest not to save the session in database, but maybe try and debug if your cookies are infact being removed somehow. You could open the browser dev tools and then test this out and see if the cookies are wiped when the issue occurs

Comment: Also, see if you have anything like this in your `settings.py`. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73764766/9544403)

Comment: @ArunT I do create random session variables. I use something like randint or something... I know it is random though. Maybe you are onto something here... I can define it in the env variables and see if that solves the issue

Comment: Another easy test would be to test this using two different browsers such as Firefox and Chrome and see if the issue persists between browsers.

Comment: I remember now that my issue was related to CSRF tokens generated in the forms. So my users would get logged out if they have more than 1 tab open, and 1 of them has a form in it. Check this post out. Although the solution in it is not a good one. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296162/opening-a-new-browser-tab-invalidates-djangos-csrf-token-preventing-form-submi). Just pointing you to see if you have this issue whenever a page with a form comes up.

Comment: @ArunT Ok so i have run some tests this morning. The first problem is that lets say I am I logged in on 3 separate browsers. Each has sessionid = {a,b,c} respectively. IF there are concurrent requests to the server ALL three will have their sessionid's overwritten with new ids = {d,e}. I am not sure what would cause this. T

Comment: @ArunT I also updated the problem-statement with current conditions. I have verified that it only occurs on a WSGI server and not my development server... I am not sure why that would happen. The error occurs on ALL browser types... this means it is in fact a server error. One additional peice of information is that the new session ids that are returned are much shorter than the originals...

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your problem, but why are you a custom authentication backend to authenticate clients? Seems like you could use the normal ModelBackend.

Comment: @NickODell I think this is related. I wish I could have used the normal ModleBackend but I have a custom use case for users so in order to align with the way I was storing users I needed a different way of authenticating? For example, my users table in my database is given like 5 different columns of attributes instead of the regular ones django uses. I guess I could just try to implement a custom user instead of writing the custom authentication?

Comment: @BenP In the past, I've used [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) for that kind of thing.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for your help... I was able to clean up my code and get it working similarly by just using custom user model. However, this did not fix the sessions overwritting themselves! Thanks for solving a different problem though or helping me clean up my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ArunT @NickODell Thanks for your help!

The sessionid is getting overwritten by the server on concurrent calls because the secret key is different for different instances of the WSGI server. The problem is with the way I was assigning a secret key

More specifically, you cannot generate a random key for your SK
Bad code:

```
 SECRET_KEY = secrets.token_urlsafe(50)
 os.environ['DJANGO_SESSION_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
```

The correct way to do this is to get a set secret key from pipeline variables!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, many things are tied to the secret key. Never put it in code, always environment variables, or read from a key store like Azure Keyvault, etc